# Maximum multi-display resolution for Intel HD-520 & Nvidia 940M laptop

Tags: graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, resolution, intel-graphics

I'm considering a new laptop (ASUS UX303UB) that has Intel HD-520 graphics *and* has a discrete GPU in the Nvidia 940M. The believe the laptop has a mini-DisplayPort (1.2) and an HDMI 1.4 port. The laptop has a screen with, 3200 x 1800 resolution

I know the 940M and the HD-520 graphics are both capable of supporting a UHD/4K display, but I'm unsure if they can each support a UHD/4K display at the *same time*.

I'm guessing that the laptop *might* be able to run 2 UHD/4K monitors, but probably only when the laptop's screen is off?

In order to get 3 screens, would that presumably mean running a single UHD/4K monitor, and then potentially having a 1080p monitor, and then running the laptop's own screen at a lower resolution? Or would I perhaps be able to keep the native resolution of the laptop screen, and drive a 1080p monitor over USB3.

Comment: nice question, usually you will need a DisplayPort-Connector with 60Hz of Graphics Frequency or more, to support a flickerfree 2K or 4K screen, the HD-520 should be able to support up to 4K